# How to get the currently running scene's class in cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

With `cocos2d-iphone` 1.0.1:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]runningScene]class]
```

This returns `CCScene`.

But I need to know whether it is my `Title` or `Battle` or `Shop` scenes...

I am modifying the `applicationWillEnterForeground` method in the AppDelegate, and I'd like to do different things depending on the current scene. Getting a plain `CCScene` doesn't help me much.

Is there a way to determine which scene is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
CCScene *scene = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]runningScene];
CCLayer *layer = [[scene  children] objectAtIndex:0];

if([layer isKindOfClass:[MainMenu class]])
{
    printf("Yes\n");
}
```

Comment: But how safe is this? Is it possible for the children array to be empty?

Comment: You can check children count..if it is more than 1 then only access.

Comment: I did that already, but the point is, can one be sure that the first child in a scene is always the scene layer? Can't there be an instance where, dunno, the first child is something else and the layer is in some other index, etc?